# Microsoft Excel Can't make y-axis cross at first x-axis value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this graph (image 1) where I want the y-axis to cross the x-axis at the first value. But when I go to settings and set it to "Vertical axis crosses" -> "at category number" -> set to 1, it doesn't work and the y-axis cross before the first x-axis value. When I set that to 2, it crosses at a value that's too high (image 2).

How can I make this work? In the y-axis settings, I can set the value at which I want the x-axis to cross, but not the other way around.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing the crossing point, why not just set the lower limit for the x-axis to the x-value of your first point, in this case 50? Seems to work on the graph i tried it with in Excel 2016.

All the changes you need to do however are in the format settings of the x-axis, not y! Either setting the lower limit of the x-axis to the x-value of your first point (not 1 but 50) or setting the "axis crosses" value to the x-value of your first potnt (again, not 1 but 50) should do the trick.

You can access the settings for the x-axis by doubleclicking on any part of the x-axis (e.g. one of the numbers on it), the panel shows up on the right.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement of Bombaglad, I will show screenshots from Excel 365.

Besides, please make sure there is not duplicate "50" in the data range of X-axis.

This image is for Y-axis.

[image]

This image is for X-axis.

[image]